# why firmware is part of a driver. Is it important, Can I exclude it from a driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, firmware

First why firmware is important. For example in real drivers I see there is DMA or MMIO read/write is done, but normally driver code in Linux add firmware struct after requesting it from Kernel using `request_firmware` function.

why should I add firmware in PCI driver when i can read and write to device from driver using direct memory access. DMA is totally different and has nothing to do with firmware. DMA map device object to kernel virtual page and firmware struct object simple has read and write operations.which I don't know why they are needed. For example for typical driver this function is a struct of firmware write operations

```
           typedef void (*my_driver_write_phy)(struct mydriver_private *o, int register, int val);
```

This function is registered as a callback and member of my driver's firmware struct. so I guess Kernel calls this function. But my question is, when does kernel call this function. is it used for additional features (please explain if  it can be excluded) or is it called every time  when data transfer happen from device to/from system including when DMA memory is accessed

So basically real question is: IS firmware required also for Direct Memory access? AND can it be excluded

Comment: The driver know which and how to load the firmware, but firmware is now often in the filesystem, and kernel will search and pass to driver. You are free to decide on and when to load the firmware (and how) (but consider license implications). DMA is a protocol (and hardware support), but devices could requires firmware to do any operation (the instructions for the device microprocessor).

Comment: The device might power up with only enough functionality to allow its firmware to be loaded, and become fully functional only after the firmware is loaded.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Can firmware be developed using only native C/without any libraries and if use libraries then what is Yocto. and what is `Target run-time binaries:` and does target run-time binaries include entire operating system to be transferred to some device. on this page its say `These include the bootloader, kernel, kernel modules, root filesystem image.` from this source https://opensource.com/article/18/6/embedded-linux-build-tools

Comment: @IanAbbott Can firmware be developed using only native C/without any libraries and if use libraries then what is Yocto. and what is Target run-time binaries: and does target run-time binaries include entire operating system to be transferred to some device. on this page its say `These include the bootloader, kernel, kernel modules, root filesystem image` . from this source https://opensource.com/article/18/6/embedded-linux-build-tools

Comment: and is there any device I can find easily available find anywhere/or making my computer a embedded linux system. Can I have a embedded device that can connect to multiple cameras and also wifi connection as embedded device so I can start developing embedded linux systems and testing and deployment. I have multiple Linux computers

Comment: also in `struct _firmware` there is `_write_mac` and `_write_phy` callbacks assigned. what are `mac` and `phy`

Comment: Firmware is done in C or in assembler or both. Often without libraries (you do not have much memory), and if there are libraries, they are very simple (e.g. interface to I2C, seriam, usb, ...). I think Yocto is more about embedded system, not embedded devices (e.g. firmware like coreboot, so to boot the system, with main CPU, kernel intergration and basic OS services). You may want to check freedombox (really free embedded system, and with a lot of documentation and different hardware support). Then the OS and task are much different, but you have the structure. Raspberry PI is also used.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi what is `_phy` and `_mac` callbacks assigned inside normal drivers to `struct _firmware` is `__phy` includes `pm core`/device power management. and what is `__mac` in firmwares?

Comment: I don't know where `struct _firmware` is defined, but `request_firmware` uses `struct firmware`, not `struct _firmware`, and `struct firmware` does include any of those mac and phy callbacks. I guess those are something to do with drivers for Ethernet NICs.

Comment: @IanAbbott those function callsbacks for firmware are checking something like `#defined RTL_GIGA_MAC_VER_02` or something similar named in `if` statements and then write to device registers like `writel` to `mmio` write. but do u know what `mac version`  is. Or is there any thing like mac version in mac address for Ethernet card. Or is it just something like a firmware normally has to do with mac address types checking for different devices from same vendor to differentiate between devices since a single driver enables multiple devices from same vendor.

Comment: even while calling functions like `dma_set_mask_and_coherent` these mac version are checked using `if(,...)`like `if (sizeof(dma_addr_t) > 4 && tp->mac_version >= RTL_GIGA_MAC_VER_18 &&
     !dma_set_mask_and_coherent(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(64))) {dev->features |= NETIF_F_HIGHDMA;}`

Comment: can a NIC device not able to support DMA?

Comment: So this question is really about the r8169 driver? That driver seems to support various RealTek cards, and different variants of those cards requiring different firmware. Some of the variants support 64-bit DMA addresses and others only support 32-bit DMA addresses. The `NETIF_F_HIGHDMA` feature is only used if the computer and the device variant both support 64-bit DMA addresses.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes I am looking into `r8169` driver. do u know this driver?

Comment: @Alex No, but it looks large and complicated. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott is there any other driver which is short and simple to understand and functional means I can use browsing,etc. simple functionality. for `Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)`

Comment: @IanAbbott can u please tell me what are `phy` registers? they are different from MMIO registers and DMA but they are also needed like for every card variant from realtek. I am using r8169 variant. Can I not use `__phy_write` to write to phy register instead use `writel`/or mapping phy register to DMA area? Can I do this?

Comment: @IanAbbott basically the driver is pretty short for variant that I use. if I remove other variants code from the driver and just use the one which is usable with my device variant. Do u know is there a command to figure that out which variant of device is in use

Comment: It looks like it uses the upper 12 bits of the TxConfig register to identify the device: `xid = (RTL_R32(tp, TxConfig) >> 20) & 0xfcf;` `chipset = rtl8169_get_mac_version(xid, tp->supports_gmii);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott any idea of `& 0xfcf`? why is it Anding with what's read from TxcConfig register

Comment: No idea. You would have to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: u mean emailing them? on this page it says their email is `nicfae@realtek.com`. Do u think they can tell these types of info. and is this common for driver developer to contact device makers for info  like this https://www.realtek.com/en/contact-us-en/cu-1-en-2/cu-1-taiwan-en